# Implementing a --assume-yes/--assume-no command line flag to affect a `input()` based `confirm()` function

Tags: python, comparative-review

I have a Python command line application that needs to ask the user for confirmation at some point. I want to add a `--assume-yes`/`--assume-no` command line flag to skip the confirmation. I have several ideas how to handle this flag and am not sure which is good/best/terrible.

## Initial code

```py
# main.py, this file is simplified, "work" knows nothing about the structure of "args"
import cli, interactive

def work(foo):
    if interactive.confirm(f"do you want {foo}"):
        print("ok, I will do it")
    else:
        print("skipping")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = cli.parse()
    work(args.foo)
```

```py
# cli.py, this is simplified
import argparse

def parse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--foo")
    parser.add_argument("--assume-yes", action="store_true", dest="assume",
                        default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--assume-no", action="store_false", dest="assume")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # how to handle args.assume at this point? see below for my ideas
    return args
```

```py
# interactive.py, this is the original function from my project
def confirm(message: str, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
    """Ask the user for confirmation on the terminal.

    :param message: the question to print
    :param accept_enter_key: Accept ENTER as alternative for "n"
    :returns: the answer of the user
    """
    while True:
        answer = input(message + ' (y/N) ')
        answer = answer.lower()
        if answer == 'y':
            return True
        if answer == 'n':
            return False
        if answer == '' and accept_enter_key:
            return False
        print('Please answer with "y" for yes or "n" for no.')
```

## Ideas how to handle `args.assume`

I came up with three ideas but I can find something about each idea that I don't like:

1. replace `interactive.confirm` with another function dynamically

   ```py
   # insert this into cli.py
       if args.assume is not None:
           import interactive
           interactive.confirm = lambda _, __=None: args.assume
   ```

   I do not like this because it changes a function on the fly. I like it because I can forget the `args.assume` thing in the rest of my application. It does not show up in the unit  tests of `interactive.confirm`.
2. add an extra argument to all functions that call `interactive.confirm` and to the function itself:

   ```py
   # in interactive.py
   def confirm(message: str, assume: bool|None, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
       if assume is not None:
           return assume
       ...
   # in main.py
   def work(foo, assume):
       if interactive.confirm(f"do you want {foo}", assume):
       ...

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       args = cli.parse()
       work(args.foo, args.assume)
   ```

   I don't like this because I have to change the signature of many functions in my program and the new argument has to be tested in the unittest of interactive.confirm.
3. save the value of `args.assume` to a global variable that is read by `interactive.confirm`:

   ```py
   # insert this into cli.py
       if args.assume is not None:
           import interactive
           interactive.assume = args.assume
   # and in interactive.py
   def confirm(message: str, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
       if assume is not None:
           return assume
       ...
   ```

   This (nearly) has the advantage of (1) because it does not touch any other code but the command line parser and `confirm`. But it uses a global mutable variable to toggle program behaviour which I thought was bad style.

## Question

What do you think about my ideas to implement the assume logic? What pros and cons did I forget? Do you know another way to implement it?

## Background

The console application is [khard](https://github.com/lucc/khard/). `confirm` is called directly in nine places by six other functions. Some of these get called by other functions in turn.

Comment: _"But it uses a global mutable variable to toggle program behaviour which I thought was bad style."_ yes, to an extent. But monkey-patching **is** treating functions as global mutable variables, which also has the lovely side-effect of making your code impossible to read.

Answer (score 6):

Of the three approaches, the first seems best to me.  We can do a little better by giving names to the the "assume" versions of the function, and include them in `interactive.py`:

```
def confirm(message: str, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
    # implementation unchanged

def assume_yes(_: str, __:bool = True):
    return True

def assume_no(_: str, __:bool = True):
    return True
```

Then we can set the implementation to use in `args`:

```
    parser.add_argument("--assume-yes", action="store_const",
                        const=interactive.assume_yes, dest="confirm",
                        default=interactive.confirm)
    parser.add_argument("--assume-no", action="store_const",
                        const=interactive.assume_no, dest="confirm")
```

Then use `args.confirm()` in place of `interactive.confirm()` throughout the code.

I think this is more amenable to unit-testing, and avoids global state (either explicit in global variables or implicit by assigning to `interactive.confirm`).

---

A review of the `confirm()` implementation:

> ```
>        answer = input(message + ' (y/N) ')
> ```

This is misleading, as `n` is default only if `accept_enter_key` is true.  We should be showing `(y/n)` here if there's no default answer.

We can only accept "no" as default; that might be sufficient for this application, but a more generally useful implementation would allow the second argument to be true, false or none:

```
def confirm(message: str, default: Optional[bool] = None) -> bool:
    # implementation unchanged
    """Ask the user for confirmation on the terminal.

    :param message: the question to print
    :param default: the default answer if user just presses Enter
    :returns: the answer of the user
    """
    keys = ['n', 'y']
    get_key = lambda v: (str.lower,str.upper)[v == default](keys[v])
    prompt = f"{message} ({get_key(True)}/{get_key(False)}) "
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        answer = answer.lower()
        if answer == keys[True]:
            return True
        if answer == keys[False]:
            return False
        if answer == '' and default is not None:
            return default
        print('Please answer with "y" for yes or "n" for no.')
```

This is also one step closer to internationalising this function (since we now use the `keys` array rather than embedding `y` and `n` in multiple places).

Comment: Passing `args.confirm` around is actually more than "a little better" than monkey-patching as it takes care of corner cases such as some modules using an `from interactive import confirm` approach and all of a sudden you can't understand why one of your `confirm` call does not use the patched version and still ask you for confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

Don't assign to `args` within the `__main__` guard - it's still global; it needs to be moved to a function.

`--assume-yes` and `--assume-no` need to be mutually exclusive for the `argparse` setup to make sense. The easiest way is to convert this to one argument that accepts `yes` or `no`. Or use [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group).

I recommend that you use early short-circuiting for `assume` and not work it into the logic of the `confirm` function itself, which shouldn't concern itself with command-line parameters. There are many ways; I demonstrate a simple dict-based one that's a variation of your (1). This is a form of the [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern.

The way it's shown with monkey-patching (2) is not great; better to pass the method in rather than replacing it for the entire module.

Don't do (3) the global-variable approach.

The current default for `confirm` is `False`. You can make this parametric if you want. The typical format for Unix-likes to indicate enter-defaults is to surround them in brackets, and (EBNF-like) pipe-separated options, as in `[y]|n`.

Don't thread `args` through the program; it's weakly-typed. It should terminate in `main`.

### Suggested

```py
import argparse
from typing import Protocol


def parse_bool(string: str) -> bool:
    prefix = string.lower()[:1]
    if prefix in {'y', 'n'}:
        return prefix == 'y'
    raise ValueError('Invalid input')


def parse() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foo', help='it is a mystery')
    parser.add_argument('--assume', help='it is a mystery', type=parse_bool)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


class ConfirmCall(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, message: str, default: bool | None = False) -> bool:
        ...


def confirm_input(message: str, default: bool | None = False) -> bool:
    prompt = (
        f'{message} ('
        f'{"[y]" if default is True else "y"}|'
        f'{"[n]" if default is False else "n"})? '
    )

    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if answer == '' and default is not None:
            return default
        try:
            return parse_bool(answer)
        except ValueError:
            pass


CONFIRM_METHODS: dict[bool | None, ConfirmCall] = {
    None: confirm_input,
    True: lambda *args, **kwargs: True,
    False: lambda *args, **kwargs: False,
}


def work(foo: str, confirm: ConfirmCall) -> None:
    if confirm(f'Do you want {foo}'):
        print('it is a mystery')
    else:
        print('it is even more of a mystery')


def main() -> None:
    args = parse()
    confirm = CONFIRM_METHODS[args.assume]
    work(args.foo, confirm)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

An online search for "python configuration management" will return a slew of libraries and articles proposing solutions related to this topic. Which suggests there isn't a single answer that makes sense in all cases.

#### Global variables

Contrary to the other answer I suggest variations on option 3 (i.e., global variables) in combination with the `namespace` argument to `parse_args()`. The namespace argument lets you provide an **object** to which parsed cli arguments are attached. Remember, everything is an object, so you can pass in a class, and instance of a class, a module, function, method, etc. (Ironically, you can't pass in `object()`, because a bare object doesn't have the machinery to add attributes)

For small programs (1 or a small number of files), pass in the main module as the namespace to `parse_args()`, and the results of are created as globals.

```
import argparse
import sys

# Global constants. These are default values, 
# but can be set by cli options
ASSUME_YES = None
FOO = 6.02e23

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", dest='FOO')
parser.add_argument("--assume-yes", action="store_true", dest="ASSUME_YES",
                    default=None)

parser.parse_args(namespace=sys.modules['__main__'])
```

This will then store the results of cli parsing as attributes on the main module, which makes them global variables. Use ALL CAPS variable names for `dest` in `add_argument()` to make them look like traditional "manifest constants".

#### Module level variables

If the program has more than a few files/modules, this technique can be modified to create module level constants. Group the cli arguments by module and use `parse_known_args()`:

```
import argparse
import interactive
import sys

# Global constants. These are default values, 
# but can be set by cli options
ASSUME = None
FOO = 6.02e23

# main args get turned into globals
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
main_parser.add_argument("--foo", dest='FOO')
ns, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args(namespace=sys.modules['__main__'])

# these cli args get turned into module level
# variables in the interactive.py module
interactive_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
interactive_parser.add_argument("--assume-yes", 
                                action="store_true",
                                dest="ASSUME_YES",
                                default=None)
_, unknown_args = interactive_parser.parse_known_args(args=unknown_args,
                                                namespace=interactive)   # <<<
```

`parse_known_args()` returns the namespace and a list of any args that weren't parsed, i.e., the unknown args. The calls to `parse_known_args()` are setup in a chain so that unknown args from one call are passed on to the next call. If desired add a final call to `parse_args()` to collect any remaining cli arguments that don't need special handling.

Obviously, this code could be reorganized so that each module has a function to parse the cli args it recognizes and sets module level variables, and returns the unparsed cli args.

#### Global and/or module config objects

If you don't like global or module level variables, use a config object:

```
import argparse
import sys

# default configuration, some values can be set
# by cli arguments
config = argparse.Namespace(
    assume_yes=None,
    foo=6.02e23
)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", dest='foo')
parser.add_argument("--assume-yes", action="store_true", dest="assume_yes",
                    default=None)

parser.parse_args(namespace=config)   # <<<<
```

This creates a global "config" object with attributes set to the cli args. Code similar to the code in the module level variables can be used to set module level config objects.

#### interactive.py

To minimize changes to other code,

```
# rename the old confirm()
def interactive_confirm(message: str, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
    ...

# add a new confirm() that implements the assume-yes/no logic
def confirm(message: str, accept_enter_key: bool = True) -> bool:
    if ASSUME_NO:
        return False

    return ASSUME_TRUE or interactive_confirm(message, accept_enter_key)
```

#### Globals in Python

To change a global or module level variable from inside a function requires some deliberate steps like:

- assigning to something of the form "module_name.var_name"
- using a `global` or `nonlocal` statement
- using `setattr()` on a module

Without taking those steps, an assignment just creates a function local variable. So in Python, global variables may not be a bad as some other languages.